# Can't use ? when redirect 301 with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo, pagerank

I have a website which is being renewed.

It has url's like site.com/page.php?p=company&l=nl
The new URL is site.com/company

I would like to use .htaccess to redirect 301.
(***I would like to keep the SEO pagerank for the old pages***)

Because of the ? it doesn't work.

This is the rule I use in my htaccess which **doesn't** work:

```
Redirect 301 /page.php?p=company&l=nl http ://www.site.com/company
```

This is the rule I use in my htaccess which **does** work:

```
Redirect 301 /page.php http ://www.site.com/company
```

I need the ?p=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=company&l=nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http ://www.site.com/company? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Remove the space between http and :

Comment: Thank you so much!! 

I wonder if Google will change the URL after some time in the searchresults, prolly it will :D

Comment: They will once it is re-crawled